# How to get current working directory path of a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program in C++ using the Qt library. I would like to get current working directory of my program. I found the **QDir::currentPath()** and **QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()** function but they give back the directory where the application executable is. I don't wanna get the directory that contains the application executable.

I have uploaded the image which describes the path that I want to get.

[image]

Does anyone has any solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: don't see an executable in the path/folder.

Comment: what do you mean by I want the executable but not the binary ?

Comment: `QDir::currentPath()` *is* the current application directory. It is *not* the directory containing the executable, unless those two directories happen to be the same. Which is what happens in your case because Creator launches the executable that way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your application cannot know where the project is, because this is a qt-creator option. If you want to run your binary in the project path you have to setup your working directory **inside** qt-creator to the correct path. Then `QDir::currentPath()` will return the path you want to have.

goto: *projects->[environment]->run->working directory*

Comment: Thanks for your quickly reply. I understood your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath), it tries to figure out the directory the executable is in, rather than checking the current working directory

Answer (score 1):

The source code directory is available via `qmake` variables and can "defined" for access within C++ source files:

```
# Demo.pro:
# set PROJECT_PATH to the "project path" with a trailing slash
DEFINES += PROJECT_PATH=\"\\\"$${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/\\\"\"

// mainwindow.cpp
qDebug() << "Able to find main.cpp?..." 
         << QFile::exists(PROJECT_PATH "main.cpp"));
```

Output:

```
Able to find main.cpp?... true
```