# Path to the project current dir in qt

Tags: qt, relative-path

I want to get a path to the project directory in Qt and reference the other files of my project relative to it. I know this issue have been already discussed here
[Get current working directory in a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402576/get-current-working-directory-in-a-qt-application)
and here 
[How to get current working directory path of a Qt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646700/how-to-get-current-working-directory-path-of-a-qt-application)
but the answer is still unknown. In case it's impossible to get such a path then what is the approach of navigation among files of the Qt project.

Comment: Do you need path to the binary file of your application, or path to the .pro file?

Comment: path to the .pro file

Comment: `$$PWD` is for project working directory (in .pro file)

Comment: If your executable has the same name than the directory of your working directory, this work for me: QFileInfo(".").absolutePath() + "/" + QApplication::applicationName()

Comment: This command yields for me the path to binary files.
How one can acquire value of $$PWD?

Comment: For what reason do you want to do this? There may be a better way with either using a resource container or simply copying the file(s) to your build target directory

Comment: To access some images are being used in my programme I could of course put them into build target directory, but it becomes uncomfortable to pass my code to others. So, I decided to use a path relative to the build target  directory until would find more elegant decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are trying to:

> Access some images which are being used in my program. I could of course put them into build target directory, but it becomes uncomfortable to pass my code to others.

The approach to store resource files in the project source directory **and** rely on such structure at runtime is not a greatest idea. I can't imagine the situation when mixing the concepts of initially decoupled *source* and *build* directories could be useful, correct me if I'm wrong.

So, according to your needs:

- The most simple and plain way is to use the [Qt resource system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html). The resource files are simply embedded into the executable, so there will be no need to access the file system.
- Another way is the automatic deployment of the needed files. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058744/2004438) describes the way to copy your files to the target directory using `qmake`.

Comment: Thanks. Qt resource system is what I need.